# Keep Zero after decimal ( getting removed when adding two double numbers)

Tags: php

```
print(4.0+4.0);
```

I want it to output 8.0 instead of 8 . Looks like + discards the useless zero from the output. Any way I can keep it?

Comment: `print(number_format(4.0+4.0,1));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `number_format()` for numeric formation.

For your example:

`print(number_format(4.0+4.0,1));`

If it is a large number, you can still use it.

e.g. `print(number_format(404.0+808.0,1,".",""));`

This function automatically rounds the value too.

e.g. `print(number_format(4.5+4.46,1,".",""));`

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

**Edit**

Another function for sum:

`echo bcadd(4.0, 4.0, 1);`

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php)

[**Code Snipet**](https://eval.in/792014)

**EDIT - After Comment**

```
$A = 4.44;
$B = 5.56;
$loc = strpos($A,'.')?explode('.',$A):(strpos($B,'.')?explode('.',$B):0);
$len = isset($loc[1])?strlen($loc[1]):0;
print(number_format($A+$B,$len,".",""));
```

This can be helpful to you!

Comment: yes that get's the work done for the given example.  but we need to know the decimal point for that. What if I need 4.00 + 4.00 = 8.00?  It's more like how we do it paper. another example 4.444 + 4.556 = 9.000 . Basically I don't want any zeros to be removed. I hope my point is clear.

Comment: For that, You can change decimal point accordingly. `print(number_format(4.00+4.00,2));` You can get length of 0s after '.' and can put it in function.

Comment: still two problems. 1.) I don't know the number I'll be adding so I can't know the number of decimal points beforehand 2.) As for getting length after . that's don't seems possible as well. Return value after adding number's don't have decimal point if all after  point are zero..  Thanks for your help. I was thinking there must be some easy way for it.

Answer (score 0):

use `sprinf` to Format the Output or `printf`:

```
sprintf("%.0f", 4.0+4.0)
```

or

```
printf("%.0f", 4.0+4.0)
```

For more informations about `sprintf` see the  [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php) or `prinf` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.printf.php).